# Getting 'PermissionError: [error 13] permission denied when using shutil.copyfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'am using the following code to copy content of folder `PStool` into folder `c:/WINDOWS/System32`. I am running the program as admin

```
import shutil

import os

programSourcePath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Utilities_Installers_new\Programs"

pstoolfiles = os.listdir(programSourcePath + '/PSTools')

for name in pstoolfiles:
        srcname = os.path.join(programSourcePath + '/PSTools', name)
        shutil.copyfile(srcname, r'c:/WINDOWS/System32')
```

Getting

> ```
> PermissionError: [error 13] permission denied : 'c:/WINDOWS/System32'
> ```

Comment: How are you running it as admin?

Answer (score 1):

copyfile() destination should be complete filename. As per Pythons docs:

> ```
> shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
>
> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named src to a file named dst.
> dst must be the complete target file name; look at shutil.copy() for a copy 
> that accepts a target directory path.
> ```

Try this:

```
import shutil
import os

programSourcePath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Utilities_Installers_new\Programs"

pstoolfiles = os.listdir(programSourcePath + '/PSTools')

for name in pstoolfiles:
    srcname = os.path.join(programSourcePath + '/PSTools', name)
    dstname = os.path.join(r'c:/WINDOWS/System32', name)
    shutil.copyfile(srcname, dstname)
```

Comment: Yes I know and 'c:/WINDOWS/System32' is final target name

Comment: Correct me if i have not understood it properly. You are trying to copy files into the 'c:/WINDOWS/System32' directory. CopyFile expects complete destination not directory. you should append file name also in the destination then your files will be copied in the folder.

Comment: I want to copy content of the folder PSTools into the folder c:/WINDOWS/System32 so files will under System32 folder

Comment: is there other way? PSTool contain 15 files with different name do I need specify each file?